# Validating dynamically created input elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with dynamically created input elements

```
<input type='button' value='Add Another Product' id='aprod'>
<table id='page3_inside'>
    <tr id='ln1'>
        <td>
            <label for="product_cat">Product Category</label><br>
            <input type='text' class="input product_category" name="product_category[]" style="font-family:verdana; width:150px; border: 1px solid #000000;">
        </td>

        <td>
            <label for="qty">Qty</label><br>
            <input type="text"  value="" class="input qty" style="width:100px;" name="qty[]" placeholder="Qty" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"/>  
        </td>

        <td>
            <label for="unit">Unit</label><br>
            <input type='text' class="input unit" style="width:100px;" name="unit[]">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for="brand">PO Number</label><br>
            <input type="text" value="" class="input po" name="po[]" placeholder="PO Number" style='width:150px; height:28px;'/>
        </td>

    </tr>               
    </table>
```

The jQuery for appending elements:

```
<script>
$('#aprod').on('click', function() {
    $('#ln1').clone().appendTo('#page3_inside');
    prodnum = prodnum + 1;
    $('#conf_prodnum').val(prodnum);
});
</script>
```

How do I validate each input, since all fields belongs to a class.
In the example I used ID as a selector, but how to do it with class instead?

Thanks.

Comment: You mean for required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a loop like this:

```
$('form').submit(function() {  

    $('form input.input').each(function() {

        var valid = 1;

        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).addClass('error');
            valid = 0;
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('error');
        }

    });

    if (valid === 1) {
        // submit form
    } else {
        console.log('error');
        return false;
    }

});
```

You might need to change the selector and the condition to check for something more than just empty inputs but those are easy enough.

I'm not quite sure what they are supposed to be since your inputs are in a table in the question, there could be a containing `form` tag for all I know.

You can also add some styles for inputs with errors to highlight them when form submission has failed:

```
input.input.error {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I did this using id as selector but how to do it with class as
>   selector?

`$('.conf_prodnum')` A dot instead a hash is going to work on classes rather than ids.

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop to visit every element that contains class input and check your inputs like so:

```
 var inputs= $('.input ')
 for(x in inputs){
   x = inputs[x];
   //do whatever you want
 }
```

Comment: .each() is another alternative, I do more Javascript, hence this solution.